# Login Error after Php Hiding

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I changed my `.htaccess` for php hiding. Now the problem is that when I try to login my site, login script does not get username and password variables from the login form. My `.htaccess` code that creates the problem is

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably redirecting a POST request that contains the login data. When a POST-request gets redirected, the data that was sent with it is not sent with the second request, which will obviously return in an error. To fix this, change the url in the login form to point at the url that is actually handling the request (e.g. not "login.php" but "login" instead).